# Replace schema in symfony

Tags: symfony, url

Is there any possibility in symfony2 which can create from http://some.url/ url something like some.url (without schema and slashes)?

The simplest solution is str_replace(["http://", "https://", "/"], ['','', ''], 'http://some.url'); but i don't like it (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is builtin php function [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php):

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: thanx ) i forgot this )

Comment: you're very welcome, can you please accept my answer.